# AJAX tick and cross control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to implement a tick and cross control for ASP.NET which acts like a pair of radiobuttons (or a checkbox) but is more visually appealing. There would be a faded tick and cross next to each other, and when one is clicked it becomes highlighted. When the other is clicked, the selection changes. I need to be able to read the selection state on server-side code.

This would need to be implemented with Javascript because I'd like to avoid unnecessary postbacks every time one of the images is clicked.

I initially thought of adapting the AJAX Control Toolkit 'Rating' control, but couldn't see how.

Any suggestions, please? I'm not very good with AJAX so example code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently implemented something very similar on a website. The "checkbox" was a styled up `<a>` tag which had two styles. `active` and `in-active`. I had some jQuery which would update the which css class was used when a user clicked on the `<a>` tag. Also when a user clicked the tag, I then updated a hidden field on the page with a value corresponding to the selected value. Then when the page is post back I can pick up the value of the hidded field.

An example would be:

```
<a href="#" id="optionone" class="checkbox-option active"><span>value one</span></a>
<a href="#" id="optiontwo" class="checkbox-option in-active"><span>value one</span></a>
<asp:HiddenField id="hfSelectedOption" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function(){
        $('.checkbox-option').click(function(){
           $('.checkbox-option').removeClass('active').removeClass('in-active').addClass('in-active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
           $('#<%=(hfSelectedOption.ClientID)).val($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    }); 
</script>
```